# Second pending intent (with unique request code) does not open activity

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-pendingintent

So I receive notifications in GcmListenerService and try to show them like this:

```
private void showNotification(String msg, String messageId, String patternIn) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.cha_ching))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int pushId = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_UNIQUE_PUSH_ID, 1);
    pushId++;
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(KEY_UNIQUE_PUSH_ID, pushId).apply();

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(PARAM_PUSH_MESSAGE_ID, messageId);
    resultIntent.putExtra(PARAM_PUSH_PATTERN_ID, patternIn);
    resultIntent.putExtra(PARAM_PUSH_ID, pushId);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    pushId,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(pushId, notification);
```

This works fine in most cases. But there is one case when it doesn't work. So:

1. Kill app
2. Send 2 notifications
3. Click on the first one -> it will open activity
4. Click on the second one -> it WON'T open activity <-- here is an issue..

Device: Samsung Galaxy S5 Android 6.0.1

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: Please show how you call showNotification() twice. Parameter values.

Comment: @greenapps Here is [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/locz2gdj6am6pkj/Screenshot%202017-12-12%2021.26.14.png?dl=0)

Basically I just get params from Intent in onHandleIntent() and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you described, opening the first `Notification` will create a new task (since the app is not running), and launch `SplashActivity` into that task. When you now click on the second `Notification` it will just bring the existing task forward and won't launch another instance of `SplashActivity`. This is the standard behaviour when launching an `Activity` that is the "root" `Activity` of a task.

To get the behaviour that you want, you should have the `Notification` launch a `NotificationActivity` (which is not your `SplashActivity`). In  `NotificationActivity.onCreate()` you can then launch your `SplashActivity` and pass the `Intent` to it. Then call `finish()` in `onCreate()` to make sure your `NotificationActivity` goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding this line:

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```